# Using Python Enum class as value in Flask-WTF RadioField choice

Tags: python, flask-wtforms

I thought I might be able to use an `Enum` to set up the choices for a `RadioField` I'd like to toggle among those enums values. However when I go to submit my form it never validates with the enums as the values for choices.

```
from enum import Enum
class CompareMode(Enum) :
    Uninitialized = "Uninitialized"
    Single  = "Single"
    Average = "Average"

class SettingsPageForm( FlaskForm ):
    # This works...    
    compareMode = RadioField( choices=[ ( "CompareMode.Single" , CompareMode.Single.value ) , ( "CompareMode.Average" , CompareMode.Average.value ) ] , default="CompareMode.Single" )
    # This does not
    compareMode = RadioField( choices=[ ( CompareMode.Single , CompareMode.Single.value ) , ( CompareMode.Average , CompareMode.Average.value ) ] , default=CompareMode.Single )
```

Does flask-wtf have constraints on the values I can provide? I know `RadioFields` come defaulted with a `Required` validator, and so I imagine something is breaking during the validation process with my enum choice which is why my form never satisfies `validate_on_submit`. Is there a workaround to this? It would be nice to receive the data from the RadioField as an enum value that I can just assign to my model, but in the meantime I'll use a string to convert back to my enum.